# Real Analysis : Directional Derivative and Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

(a) If $f(x,y)=x+y$ if $x=0$ or $y=0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise. What is the directional derivative at $C=(0,0)$ along the direction $u=(a,b),a\neq 0, b\neq 0$?

(b) If the function $f:R \rightarrow R$ (where $R$ is the real line) satisfies:
$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$ for all $x,y$ and $c$ in $R$. Then is the function $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Your function is identically zero on any such direction, thus its derivative is also identically zero.

(b) Under those hypotheses $ f $ is seen to be everywhere differentiable, since for all $ x \in \mathbb R $ you have

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\,f(1) = f(1), $$

so that $ f $ must be of the form $ f(x) = ax + b $, which is obviously uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb R $.